# SQL COALESCE function is not working with GORM

Tags: postgresql, go, null, grails-orm, coalesce

```
DB.Model(&domain.Products{}).Where("product_code", product.Product_Code).
Updates(map\[string\]interface{}{
"product_image": gorm.Expr("COALESCE(?, products.product_image)", product.Product_Image),
"size":          gorm.Expr("COALESCE(?, products.size)", product.Size),
"color":         gorm.Expr("COALESCE(?, products.color)", product.Color),
"unit_price":    gorm.Expr("COALESCE(?, products.unit_price)", product.Unit_Price),
"stock":         gorm.Expr("COALESCE(?, products.stock)", product.Stock),
})
```

It is a gorm query to manage null value insertion when we updating a table.
I want to update the table by keeping existing values there in the table if new value(incoming value) is null.
But here in my code the table updating as normal which means , both null values and not null values are updating as usual. I hope anyone can help me

I tried gorm raw query also. But it also not working

```
ar.DB.Exec("UPDATE products SET size = COALESCE(?, size) WHERE product_code = ?", product.Size, product.Product_Code)
```

Comment: In your first example, and assuming that the fields in `domain.Products` are pointers that you set, for example, as follows: `Product := domain.products{
 product_code: 42,
 product_image: nil,
 size: nil,
 color: nil,
 unit_price: nil,
 stock: &newStock,
}` -> then only the stock would be updated.

Comment: Yes, the stock is updated but along with stock all other fields also updated with null value as in my request only stock has value. But I want to update stock with new value and others with existing values.

Comment: I tried it briefly. Updated only stock, the other fields remained unchanged. Maybe you should share a minimal reproducible example? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The problem solved . The error was in the pointer reference as you mentioned in the above comment . And thank you so much for your assistance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COALESCE returns the first argument that is not `nil`.

For this to work you need to supply pointers. However, as one can see from the code snippet in your comment, no pointers are supplied. Therefore, *all* specified fields will be updated.

Specifically, your `Products` (or whatever it is called in your program) type should look more like this:

```
package domain

type Products struct {
    Product_Code  int `gorm:"not null"`
    Product_Image *string
    Size          *int
    Color         *string
    Unit_price    *float64
    Stock         *int
}
```

Note that fields are defined as pointers.

It would then be used like this:

```
newStock := 12
prod := domain.Products{    
    product_code: 42,   
    product_image: nil,     
    size: nil,  
    color: nil,     
    unit_price: nil,    
    stock: &newStock, 
}
```

Sine all fields are `nil` with the exception of `stock` only `stock` will be updated in the database.